# the object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to acess it

Tags: c#

the object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it .your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object

my script is in c#

```
    w = brick[0].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size.x;
    h = brick[0].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size.y;
    x = brick[0].transform.position.x - w/2;
    y = brick[0].transform.position.y - h/2;
    xp = ball.transform.position.x;
    yp = ball.transform.position.y;
    if (ptobcollision(x,y, w, h, xp, yp)) {
        ball.GetComponent<Ball>().YDirection = 1;
        //Debug.LogError("now Error");
        Destroy(brick[0]);
    }
```

Comment: Don't destroy your gameobject if you plan on accessing it.

Comment: i want to destroy the "GameObject" and i don't want to access it.

Comment: this is my script and i want the brick to be destroyed when hit by the ball and then i don't want to access it.

Comment: Is that script in your update() method?

Answer (score 1):

```
xp = ball.transform.position.x;
yp = ball.transform.position.y;    

if (brick[0] != null)
{
    w = brick[0].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size.x;
    h = brick[0].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size.y;
    x = brick[0].transform.position.x - w/2;
    y = brick[0].transform.position.y - h/2;

    if (ptobcollision(x,y, w, h, xp, yp)) {
        ball.GetComponent<Ball>().YDirection = 1;
        //Debug.LogError("now Error");
        Destroy(brick[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: But *why* does this work?!

Comment: Isn't it obvious?!

Comment: Obviously yes, which is why I asked.